# PHP: запись в файл vs база данных

Tags: php, mysql, файлы

Есть простенькая гостевая книга: в форме обратной связи 2 поля (имя и комментарий), аяксом данные отправляются на сервер и обратно выводятся на этой же странице.

С базой данных для такой задачи решил не заморачиваться и реализовал запись в файл и чтение из него:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$text = $_POST['text'];

if($name && $text) {
    $filename = 'file.txt';
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    $html = '<p><b>'.$name.'</b></p><p>'.$text.'</p><br />'.$content;
    file_put_contents($filename, $html, LOCK_EX);
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    echo $content;
}
```

Но есть некоторые сомнения относительно того, насколько корректно это будет работать. Прошу совета опытных разработчиков: какие есть риски в такой реализации? Можно ли положиться на такой вариант или всё-таки создавать базу, туда всё писать, оттуда выводить и т.д.?

Comment: И что получается, для каждого клиента свой или общий?

Comment: @NikolajSarry, файл общий для всех записей

Comment: Первый риск - XSS. Не используйте "голый POST". И это про ваш код, а не "файл vs БД" Второй - если файл в данный момент заблокирован, запись не произойдет, а базами данных такого не может быть. Посмотрите в сторону SQLite - без установки, без авторизации, есть везде.

Answer (score 1):

Для принятия решения необходимо найти опасные моменты.

Если, для записи в файл необходимо пройти проверку на робота, то записей будет немного.
Чтение осуществляется с общего файла, открытий тоже будет не много.
Выходит что опасности для DDOS тут нет. Возможно, что это решение будет работать даже быстрее чем с базой.

Но вот сама по себе гостевая требует оперативной проверки, лучше премодерации иначе легко попасть в черный список Роскомнадзора.

Comment: Это для локальной web-открытки: там писать будут человек 30-40, не больше (вместо капчи - секретное слово, которое они все знают). Меня смущает, не "сломается" ли файл каким-то образом - от одновременного количества многих записей, например (или как-то  ещё).

Comment: @humster_spb при такой нагрузке, на мой взгляд, это сравнимо попадания одной пули в другую)

Comment: humster_spb, нет не сломается, даже если не использовать потокобезопасные подходы, так как в случае чего у одного запись пройдет, у второго просто исключение вывалиться.

Answer (score 1):

Если используете "слабый" хостинг, который сильно ограничивает. То это выход, в противном случае лучше реализовывать с использованием БД.

Плюсы подхода:

- Не нужна БД
- Относительно малое количество кода

Минусы:

- Невозможно параллельно писать отзывы
- Большая вероятность что работает медленнее (нужен тест)
- Необходимость создания парсера для выборки данных из файла
- Не безопасно
- Не сработает при использовании "свежего" фреймворка например Laravel 5
  (но в джумле работать точно будет)

При дефиците бюджета и не возможности платить несколько сотен за хостинг- рабочий вариант, в противном случае - не стоит так делать

Comment: Выборка не нужна - отзывы выводятся на страницу по мере поступления (свежие сверху). А вот про невозможность параллельно писать отзывы - расскажите подробнее, плиз. Я тоже над этим думал, но не очень понимаю, что именно будет происходить: один человек пишет и отправляет, а у второго в этот момент ничего не отправится? Будет какое-то сообщение об ошибке? Как эта невозможность выглядит физически для конечных пользователей?

Comment: Не со всеми минусами соглашусь: Параллельно можно писать отзывы, только нужно использовать семафоры http://php.net/manual/ru/book.sem.php. Не безопасно - это почему? Парсер не сложнее чем составить SQL запрос.

Comment: @humster_spb, дело в том что запросы могут быть параллельными и у каждого свой поток, а вот файл может быть одновременно открыт только в одном потоке. Но эта проблема легко решается семафорами (ссылка в предыдущем комментарии).

Comment: @Максим я заранее предполагаю что речь идет о каком-то дешевом хостинге и о семафорах там речь не идет... А если сайт находиться на VPS то нет смысла так мучатся) разве что только из спортивного интереса)

Comment: Все таки надо учиться сразу делать правильно. Если есть вероятность попадания в эту ситуацию, то лучше ее избежать, тем более что это буквально плюс три строки кода, получил ссылку на семафор, занял его, освободил его. Все, пуля в пулю больше не попадет)